# IE dropdown disappears on click, need to mouse down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, dropdown

I don't have this problem in Chrome or Safari, it seems like a compatibility issue specific to IE (11).
When I click on the dropdown bar, my dropdown list expands for a fraction of second before disappearing. To make it last, I need to hold/mouse down. Selecting the options is also an issue. Here is the relevant JS code for the dropdown.

```
<select class="ng-valid" id="selection-timeframe.selector" aria-invalid="false" 
ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" 
ng-model="layer.dropdown.selected" 
ng-options="timeframe.name for timeframe in layer.dropdown.timeframes" 
ng-change="layer.dropdown.selectLayer(layer.dropdown)"> 
...(options)... 
</select>
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: It's more important to see the rendered HTML and any related JavaScript. That's all the browser cares about. Is there actually jQuery at play in your AngularJS app? You haven't shown any, so I removed the tag.

Comment: Is there any error in console in IE 11? You only give the html code so we can't reproduce the issue. Could you please provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including related JavaScript code to show the click event or anything related? So that we can have a test and see how to help.